# jQuery validation - syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testform").validate(function() {
    rules: {
      firstname: {
        minlength: 3,
        required: true // error is here?
      },
      surname: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },
      gender: {
        notEqualTo: "select"
      }
    },
    messages: {
      firstname: {
        required: "Zadejte své jméno",
        minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 3 znaky"
      },
      surname: {
        required: "Zadejte své příjmení",
        minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 2 znaky"
      },
      gender: {
        notEqualTo: "Zvolte pohlaví"
      }
    },
    errorContainer: "#errors"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

My web console displays me, that on line 6 (`rules.firstname.required`)  is some syntax error. I can't see it. I tried also to switch `minlength` and `required` but the error still stays on the same line.

Can somebody see it?

Comment: Please include the syntax error in your question for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Your error is that you're passing a function into `validate`:

```
$("#testform").validate(function() { // <-- here you're passing a function
  // ...
})
```

where `validate` expects an object instead:

```
$("#testform").validate({ // <-- but you should pass an object
  // ...
});
```

The syntax error is a consequence of declaring object properties on a function expression.

```
$("#testform").validate(function() {
  rules: { // <-- (*)
    // ... 
  },
  // ...
})
```

(*) You're trying to define a property on an object but are declaring a [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) within a function expression.

---

#### Syntax Error Explanation

Defining a property on a function expression is valid syntax, although that is not actually what is happening. All that means is that you're declaring a [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) which has a label and a body and just happens to be within a function expression:

```js
var x = function() {
  rules: {} // label statement with label 'rules' and a body block expression
}

console.log(x.rules); // undefined. Not really useful
```

[Parse Tree for the code above](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=var%20x%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20rules%3A%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20label%20statement%20with%20label%20'rules'%20and%20a%20block%0A%7D).

Nesting these label statements is also valid:

```js
var x = function() {
  rules: {       // label statement with label 'rules' and a body block expression
    name: 'test' // label statement with label 'name' and a literal expression 'test'
  }
}

console.log(x.rules); // undefined
```

[Parse Tree for the code above](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=var%20x%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20rules%3A%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20label%20statement%20with%20label%20'rules'%20and%20its%20block%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'test'%20%2F%2F%20label%20statement%20with%20label%20'name'%20and%20a%20literal%20expression%20'test'%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

As a matter of fact, we can even define label statements on their own:

```js
rules: {} // valid syntax for a labeled statement with a label "rules" and a body block expression
```

[Parse Tree for the code above](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=rules%3A%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20valid%20syntax%20for%20a%20labeled%20statement)

**The syntax error happens once you add a second label by wrongly assuming you are adding properties to an object.**

More accurately, the problem is the `,` ([Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)), which expects an expression but we're giving it a labeled statement instead:

```js
rules: {},   // label statement with label 'rules' and a body block expression
messages: {} // <-- syntax error: thing before the comma is not an expression
```

Not having the `,` would eliminate the error since we would just have two independent labeled statements:

```js
rules: {}    // label statement with label 'rules' and a body block expression
messages: {} // label statement with label 'messages' and a body block expression
```

That's why the error is on line 6, because that is right after the first `,`.
Removing all the commas will remove your syntax error and leave you with a bunch of labeled statements:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testform").validate(function(){
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 3
                required: true
            }
            surname: {
                minlength: 2
                required: true
            }
            gender: {
                notEqualTo: "select"
            }
        }
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Zadejte své jméno"
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 3 znaky"
            }
            surname: {
                required: "Zadejte své příjmení"
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 2 znaky"
            }
            gender: {
                notEqualTo: "Zvolte pohlaví"
            }
        }
        errorContainer: "#errors"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, this would still leave a bug in your code because you're passing wrong arguments to `validate` but at least would run :)

Comment: The interpreter reads that as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), so it is technically valid syntax, but for something else.

Comment: Valid yes, but the validator function expects an object as a param, not a function.